# Where do you shop for used gear?

Tags: microphone, portable-recorder, shopping, used-gear

I'm always looking for bargains on mics, recorders, etc. But there must be more to life than Craigslist and eBay?! Where do you shop for those killer deals?

Answer (score 4):

I'm curious to know where other people go too.  I had often wondered if there could be a section on this site for people looking to off load or pick up used gear.

Comment: love that idea……

Comment: second that idea

Answer (score 2):

So.... if I tell you you'll end up bidding against me? :)

Of course ebay and I suspect each country has a local equivalent...
I picked up my mint MKH70 w rycote & fluffy for us$800 via a local forum...

I suspect older location sound recordists probably have a mic collection some of which they wont/dont use so try wherever they congregate?

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten some decent deals on [taperssection.com](http://taperssection.com). It's a forum site for concert tapers. Once you create an account you can gain access to their Marketplace.

Answer (score 2):

jwsound.net has a buy sell section and is also a pretty good resource when it comes to on location stuff.

Answer (score 2):

[Bazza's bazaar](http://www.bblist.co.uk/index.php), mostly for UK based gear

Also [Mike's film sound](http://www.mikesfilmsound.com/used_equipment.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Would be great to find some decent used gear